# Web Service URL Not Working (PowerBI Desktop-Sql ServerReportingServices)

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi

I can access my PowerBI desktop report on Reporting Services of web portal url(manager) at `http://sivakumar/Reports`, but I am unable to access the same report on Reporting Services of Web Service URL (Viewer) at `http://sivakumar/ReportServer`.

I configured reporting service the right way and I am using Sql Server Preview Reporting Services Enterprise Evaluation  Edition 14.0.1.353

I am getting below error, can any one please help me with it?

> Reporting Services Error
>
> The operation you are attempting on item '/PowerBI_SSRS' is not allowed for this item type. (rsWrongItemType)

Answer (score 2):

Power BI reports can only be viewed or downloaded from the portal. If you need to embed Power BI reports use the &rs:embed=true parameter

Comment: Where we have to add &rs:embed=true parameter?

Comment: Just append the parameter to the end of the URL - if you are embedding in an iFrame <iframe src="http://reportserver/reports/powerbi/myReport.pbix?rsembed=true

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing this (Sep 2017), the only way seems to be to use the Report portal URL and add `?rs:embed=true`at the end.

See [Developer handbook overview, Power BI Report Server](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/reportserver-developer-handbook-overview/)

Your embedded URL should look like:

```
http://reportServerName/reports/powerbi/PowerBIReport?rs:embed=true
```